# Where are dependencies stored when we do "kpm restore"

Tags: asp.net-core

When I do `kpm restore` where can I find dependencies that were resolved? Are they on stored on disk? I was looking in folder where my .kre packages are.

Comment: @zonranpro, In solution folder in subfolder packages

Comment: @KrzysztofCieslak Thank you. I was looking in the project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`packages` folder in your project folder. If you have a `Myapp` project folder then then check in `Myapp/packages`.

Answer (score 7):

Without any arguments, `kpm restore` is now putting all the downloads in `%userprofile%\.kpm\packages`. I think that is the cache. To specify a directory, I had to do `kpm restore --packages packages`.

Comment: For me it was .k instead of .kpm